# How to create report that provides the total number of rows for each of the values in one of the report-columns

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am new to Power BI.
I need to create report that provides the total number of rows broken down by values in one of the report-columns.
I am googling and reading about measures at the moment, but so far I can't find needed soluton.
Is it possible at all with Power BI ?

Report needs to show how many rows are there for Alpine,
how many rows are there for Clark,
how many rows there are for Paramus.

DATA:

```
Col1      Col2   Col3
Paramus   NJ     1
Clark     NJ     1
Paramus   NJ     2
Alpine    NJ     1
Clark     NJ     2
Alpine    NJ     2
Paramus   NJ     3
Paramus   NJ     4
Clark     NJ     3
```

REPORT should look something like:

```
Col1      Col2   Col3
Alpine    NJ     1
Alpine    NJ     2
Total     2

Clark     NJ     1
Clark     NJ     2
Clark     NJ     3
Total     3

Paramus   NJ     1
Paramus   NJ     2
Paramus   NJ     3
Paramus   NJ     4
Total     4
```

OR

```
Col1      Col2   Col3
Paramus   NJ     1
Clark     NJ     1
Paramus   NJ     2
Alpine    NJ     1
Clark     NJ     2
Alpine    NJ     2
Paramus   NJ     3
Paramus   NJ     4
Clark     NJ     3

Total for Alpine  2
Total for Clark   3
Total for Paramus 4
```

OR

Any other way to show total number of rows with particular values.
Is the above possible at all with Power BI ?
Please help, any ideas about this kind of report will be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I created my own table with abbreviations A, C, and P. You can use a table or a matrix visual for this issue. If you load the data into Power BI you can create a measure. You can create a measure:
Count of Rows = COUNTROWS('Table')

Then use a table or matrix visual to get one of these results.
Matrix:
[Matrix Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQlqS.png)

Table:
[Table option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DyEB.png)

Comment: I am not counting number of rows in the whole table.
I need to count number of rows for each particular value in one of the columns of the report.
And I am already using table visual, which does not seem to allow to create kind of report that I've described in the description.

Comment: You can filter by the column values, and it will tell you the number of rows per value. Which I believe would be the same as number of times that value shows up. The rows actually count the number of filtered rows when you put it into a visual with a filter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SUMMARIZE function to achieve a similar result

```
New Table = SUMMARIZE(CurrentTable,[Col 1],”count”, COUNT(CurrentTable[col1]))
```

`CurrentTable` means the name of the table I have the columns in my example